# Why is my Excel 10 Megabytes large?

Tags: excel, storage, pivot-table, vba

My Excel 2010 workbook contains

4 datasheets with a table (i.e. a ListObject)

- deliveries, used range $A$1:$T$7647
- stock, used range $A$1:$V$22962
- sales, used range $A$1:$U$2348
- summary, used range $A$1:$AA$9509 (a summary of the life cycle per item, created in VBA)

7 hidden sheets with pivot tables, with on the largest one a used range of $A$1:$CS$37, that refer to the above tables

1 presentation sheet with a used range of $A$1:$X$108, containing 7 tables (ListObjects) with either formulas referring to the pivot tables, or values copied from them in VBA.

**Why is my file so huge and what can I do about it?**

*Edits in response to comments from other users:*

To make sure there are not too much cells I ever touched in the past but do not use any more, I retrieved the above ranges with

```
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Print sht.Name, sht.UsedRange.Address
Next
```

So it will not help to copy the data and the code to a new clean workbook.

There are no formulas that refer to a whole column, style `=match("anything", A:A)` , nor other formulas that refer anything outside the used range.

As I am a VBA developer, any solution should be transparent for the user. This person is not supposed to know about the internals of Excel.

Answer (score 3):

When you insert a pivot table on your workbook, **Excel caches the data from the PivotTable.dataSource**. *(That is why you need to Refresh your pivot table to incorporate changes in the source data into the pivot table.)*

The data cache is less than half as big the as worksheet Range it does cache, but significant. *(In my case it added another 2.6MB to the existing 6.5MB and apparently once above 10MB, Excel starts swapping data to disk.)*

If your source data is on a separate sheet, you can **remove the source sheet, keep your data only in the cache** and save space instead of spoiling it with your pivot tables. *(Take care you did_not_uncheck `Save data with the file`, though)*

If you need to edit the data source later on, you can "drill through" to the data from the cache by double clicking the grand total on your pivot table.

Read [Massive Excel Spreadsheets – How to Reduce the Size of Pivot Table Workbooks](http://nhsexcel.com/massive-excel-spreadsheets-how-to-reduce-the-size-of-pivot-table-workbooks/) for more details.

As a VBA programmer, I must hide all this for my customer, so I wrote

*code to extract the data and delete the pivot tables*

```
Public Sub unpackPivots()
    On Error GoTo goneWrong

    Dim PSheet As Worksheet, PTable As PivotTable, PBody As Range
    For Each PSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If PSheet.Name Like "*Pivot" Then
            Set PTable = PSheet.PivotTables(1)
            PTable.ClearAllFilters
            Set PBody = PTable.DataBodyRange
            Set PBody = PBody.Cells(PBody.Rows.Count, PBody.Columns.Count)
            PSheet.Activate
            PBody.Select
            PBody.ShowDetail = True
            Application.ActiveSheet.Name = Replace(PSheet.Name, "Pivot", "_Data")
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            PSheet.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Exit Sub
```

goneWrong:
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
        Debug.Assert False
        Err.Clear
        Resume
    End Sub

*code to create the pivot tables from the data tables and delete the tables*

```
Public Sub recreatePivots()
    On Error GoTo goneWrong

    Dim DSheet As Worksheet, DTable As ListObject
    Dim PSheet As Worksheet, PCach As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable, PBody As Range

    For Each DSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If DSheet.Name Like "*_Data" Then
            Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
                SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                sourceData:=DSheet.ListObjects(1).Name, _
                Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14 _
            )
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add Before:=DSheet
            Set PSheet = Application.ActiveSheet
            PSheet.Name = Replace(DSheet.Name, "_Data", "_Pivot")

            Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable( _
                TableDestination:=PSheet.Name + "!R3C1", _
                DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14 _
            )
```

Here comes your business dependent stuff

```
            Select Case DSheet.Name
                Case "Stock_Data"
                    PTable.PivotFields("Month").Orientation = xlPageField
                    PTable.PivotFields("Manufacturer").Orientation = xlRowField
                    PTable.PivotFields("Warehouse").Orientation = xlColumnField
                    PTable.AddDataField PTable.PivotFields("Key"), _
                        "Nr of products", xlSum
                Case Else
                    ' Some other configuration of a pivote table
            End Select
            DSheet.Delete
        End If
    Next

    Exit Sub
goneWrong:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    Debug.Assert False
    Err.Clear
    Resume
End Sub
```